# How to find partial derivative function $ P_i = \frac{b_iz_i^k}{z_i^k+\theta_i^k} $

Tags: calculus, probability, vectors, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

I have a function that converts a vector of real-valued variables $\vec z$ to a probability $\vec P$. In the elementwise version of this function, $i = 1, 2, ..., K$ and $b_i = \frac{z_i}{\sum_{v=1}^Kz_v}$. $\theta$ and k are both constants where $\theta$ is a real number and $k>0$:

$$P_i = \frac{b_iz_i^k}{z_i^k+\theta_i^k} $$

I want to find the partial derivative of $P_i$ w.r.t. $z_j$ for two cases where $i = j$ and $i \neq j$:

$$ \frac{\partial P_i}{\partial z_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j} \left( \dfrac{b_i z_i^k}{ z_i^k + \theta_i^k} \right) $$

I am having difficulty solving this problem for two reasons. First, I am not sure how to index the summation in $b_i$. Should I have a separate counter $v$ for it (as it is written at the moment), or should I change it to $j$? Additionally, when I apply the quotient rule twice, I need to find the derivative of this summation, which I am not sure how to do.

Comment: The derivative of a sum is just the corresponding summand. But something is unclear: Do you have a lower case and upper case k (K)?

Comment: Yes, the two constants are separate! Uppercase K gives the number of states, lowercase k controls the steepness of an underlying probability curve